# Can Linq to XML work with colons?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
var count = (from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("env:SE04Overprinting")
select p).Count();
```

throws an exception (kind of, it crashes out when getting there, but using a watch shows this error)

```
xmlDoc.Descendants("env:SE04Overprinting")
```

> '"env:SE04Overprinting"' threw an exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>`

I did a bit of looking around on this error but didn't find anything, then tried getting rid of the colon:

```
var count = (from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("env")
select p).Count();
```

this works. Is stripping the colons out of the file the only way around this?

Comment: That's not a semicolon. That's a colon.

Comment: @BoltClock having the right name down for it would probably have helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your XML properly declares the namespace you can do this:

```
XNamespace env = "http://namespaceinXml";
var count = (from p in xmlDoc.Descendants(env + "SE04Overprinting")...
```

**Example:**

```
<foo xmlns:env="http://foo.bar">
  <env:bar>test</env:bar>
</foo>
```

Since `bar` is within the `env` namespace you can retrieve its value like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace env = "http://foo.bar";
string bar = xdoc.Descendants(env+"bar").First().Value; //returns test
```

Make sure the `XNamespace` declaration *matches exactly* the value of the namespace within your XML.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be thinking of that colon as part of the name of the element(s) you are trying to retrieve.  It is not, it is the delimiter between the namespace prefix and the local-name.

Without a namespace declaration, `env:` is meaningless.  You need to prefix the local-name ("SE04Overprinting", in your case) with the actual namespace (look for `xmlns:env=`, somewhere above the node(s) you are looking for).

See the section: Creating an XName in a Namespace, in the [XName documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx)